Im trying to send a authorization in my backend php using nextjs axios but it renders a CORS error
The issue I'm encountering involves CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) errors when attempting to make requests from my Next.js frontend application to a PHP API backend. Despite correctly setting CORS headers on the PHP server and successfully testing the API with Postman, the requests from the frontend are being blocked due to CORS policies, causing operational disruptions.
const sendToken = async () => {
try {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/testApi.php`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`,
    },
  });

  console.log(response);
  setToken(response.data.token); // Assuming the response contains a token in the data object
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

};
this is the error that im getting
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:81/testApi.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

So did you check what status it's returning instead?

yes i did im new to this framework when i try to comment the headers part it was ok status and it returns a error that i created when i dont see any headers in request but when i uncomment the headers it shows the error

So... what status does it return, when you set the header? What code is processing the request on the server side? Does php handle preflight requests, or just the webserver?

im having a axios error the message is "Network Error"

There should be more information in the browser's Network tool, analyse the request there
